# Thread - Como utilizá-la sem congelar tela?

Tags: c#, thread, multithreading

Tenho um sistema que percorre alguns elementos html, coletando alguns links. Gostaria de por um tempo de espera, mas sempre que utilizo Thread.Sleep ele congela meu programa pelo tempo estabelecido. já utilizei Application.DoEvents(); e **Thread.Join** e nenhum deles resolveu.

E toda vez que coloco o Sleep dentro da Thread não adianta porque elas disparam uma atrás da outra, acho que o caminho correto deveria ser esperar terminar uma Thread para começar a outra, mas como fazer isso?

A cada link que eu visito crio uma thread, conforme código abaixo.

Edit: Fluxo do programa Windows Form -> Tenho um laço com N repetições, dentro desse laço visito uma pagina da web e coleto alguns links, toda vez que entro em um link eu crio uma Thread e no final dela eu mato ela com **Application.ExitThread();** Porém gostaria de dar uma pausa de 1 minuto a cada visita de url, porém ao utilizar Sleep meu form fica travado e não gostaria desse comportamento. Lembrando que no ao final do laço ele já deve ter criado dezenas de Threads.

```
private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
    {
        var th = new Thread(() =>
        {

            label5.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => label5.Text = url.ToString()));
            //.Sleep(int.Parse(txtTempoPaginas.Text)*1000);

            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            br.Navigate(url);
            Application.Run();


        });

        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
        th.Join(5000);

    }
```

Estou Utilizando o seguinte código.

```
private void runBrowserThread(Uri url) {
    var th = new Thread(() => {
        var br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
        br.Navigate(url);
        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
    var br = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (br.Url == e.Url) {
        Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {0}", e.Url);
        Application.ExitThread();   // Stops the thread
    }
}
```

Comment: Estamos falando de um projeto Windows Forms/WPF, certo? E qual o motivo real da sua espera, depende de alguma condição ou da resposta de alguma coisa? Favor descrever um pouco melhor o fluxo que seu programa deve seguir.

Comment: Edit: Fluxo do programa Windows Form -> Tenho um laço com N repetições, dentro desse laço visito uma pagina da web e coleto alguns links, toda vez que entro em um link eu crio uma Thread e no final dela eu mato ela com Application.ExitThread(); Porém gostaria de dar uma pausa de 1 minuto a cada visita de url, porém ao utilizar Sleep meu form fica travado eu não gostaria desse comportamento. Lembrando que no ao final do laço ele já deve ter criado dezenas de Threads.

Answer (score 2):

Existem diferentes formas de resolver o problema de esperar por um tempo sem travar a Thread da interface gráfica.

**1) [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), para .NET Framework 2.0+**

Como você tem um período constante e e pré-definido, um Timer consegue te avisar a cada X tempo quando que a ação deve ser realizada:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;

private void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerElapsed(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // ação individual

    // quando você souber que chegou ao fim...
    if(end)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

**2) [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx), para .NET Framework 4.5+**

Se você tem a opção de optar por uma técnica mais recente, pode optar por async/await para criar uma Task que espera por um tempo determinado. Por trabalhar com assincronia, sua Thread de interface gráfica deve continuar rodando normalmente:

```
private async Task runBrowserThread(Uri url)
{
    // espera até que a Task complete o Delay
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    // continua executando
}
```

=========================================================================

Editado: a minha primeira resposta por si só não resolveu o problema do usuário, mas mantive pois pode servir como referência para quem estiver procurando formas de não congelar a tela em aplicações Windows Forms.

Considerando que pelo seu exemplo você quer fazer um loop e esperar um tempo entre cada iteração sem travar a janela do Windows Forms, acredito que não existe uma forma prática de fazê-lo com as bibliotecas mais antigas de manipulação de Threads. Por conta disso, usarei a [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx), que é apenas .NET 4.0+ para ficar melhor para trabalharmos.

Eu resolveria esse problema transformando a parte de mandar navegar e pegar o resultado da navegação em um passo só para a sua iteração. Para isso, eu criaria um método como NavigateAsync():

```
/// <summary>
/// Classe estática apenas para tornar mais bonita a chamada ao método assíncrono para quem executa a tarefa, poderia ser um método qualquer dentro do próprio Form ou uma classe separada
/// </summary>
public static class WebBrowserExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Carrega os resultados de uma navegação no WebBrowser através de um método assíncrono
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="webBrowser">Instância de WebBrowser</param>
    /// <param name="urlString">Caminho da URL a ser navegada</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs> NavigateAsync(this WebBrowser webBrowser, string urlString)
    {
        // precisamos dele para controlar o nosso contexto assíncrono, que não teríamos iniciando Threads
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs>();

        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler handler = delegate(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // indicamos o fim do TaskCompletionSource retornando o argumento do evento
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(e);
        };

        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += handler;

        webBrowser.Navigate(urlString);

        // com o await, podemos esperar que o evento DocumentCompleted nos retorne os valores
        var navigationResult = await taskCompletionSource.Task;

        // é interessante desregistrar esse evento, porque caso contrário ao longo do loop vamos cair várias vezes no handler para Tasks já finalizadas
        // se não desregistrarmos aqui, teríamos que verificar por taskCompletionSource.Task.IsCompleted até encontrarmos a chamada ao Task que estamos manipulando de fato
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted -= handler;

        return navigationResult;
    }
}
```

Fiz uns comentários no código, mas para quem não tem muita familiaridade com a TPL, basicamente usamos o [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) para manipular a nossa Thread de maneira mais controlada. Com ele, conseguimos definir que devemos esperar a chamada a SetResult() para finalizar a execução, retornando uma referência a Task para ser utilizado com async/await por outros .

Para resolver o fluxo que você descreveu, eu usei como exemplo um método de evento de clique de um botão Windows Forms:

```
/// <summary>
/// Método que inicia o processamento. Não precisa ser um evento de clique de botão, basta ser um método assíncrono para iniciar a verificação
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private async void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // como você disse que está em um loop, vamos exemplificar em um
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Iniciando i=[{1}]", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), i));

        // navegamos e esperamos a resposta, mas mantendo uma escrita síncrona
        var navigationResult = await webBrowser1.NavigateAsync("http://www.google.com.br");

        // só por causa da forma como você fez no DocumentCompleted, comparando os dois
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} i=[{1}] {2} {3}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), i, webBrowser1.Url.ToString(), navigationResult.Url.ToString()));

        // força a espera por uns 2 segundos
        await Task.Delay(2000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Acabou!", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")));
}
```

Executando esse exemplo, tive uma saída:

```
02/02/2016 12:02:26 Iniciando i=[0]
02/02/2016 12:02:29 i=[0] https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl
02/02/2016 12:02:31 Iniciando i=[1]
02/02/2016 12:02:34 i=[1] https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl
02/02/2016 12:02:36 Iniciando i=[2]
02/02/2016 12:02:38 i=[2] https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl
02/02/2016 12:02:40 Iniciando i=[3]
02/02/2016 12:02:43 i=[3] https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl
02/02/2016 12:02:45 Iniciando i=[4]
02/02/2016 12:02:47 i=[4] https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl
02/02/2016 12:02:50 Acabou!
```

Pelo fato de utilizarmos async/await no método de clique do botão, você pode perceber que o método não bloqueia a Thread da Interface Gráfica em momento algum, e ao mesmo tempo conseguimos dar um tempo de espera durante a execução do loop.

Comment: Diego, Não deu muito certo pq utilizo webbrowser e seto um evento de quando carregar a pagina clicar em alguns link dentro do evento:

**var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            br.Navigate(url);**

Oq ocorre é que nunca termina esse evento ele faz milhares de disparos, no código antigo eu utilizava Application.ExitThread(); e ele terminava. Se coloco o Application.ExitThread(); ele agora fecha meu programa.

Comment: Qual dos dois casos você tentou e como ficou? Se possível, edite a sua pergunta com o código que está tentando.

Não entendi a necessidade daquela criação de threads dentro do método, mas os 2 casos a princípio deveriam funcionar independentemente disso.

Comment: Estou utilizando async Task Como faria para criar muitas Threads? Exemplo tenho um For com 200 paginas cada vez que passo dentro desse for posso chamar **private async Task runBrowserThread(Uri url)** ? Meu problema é que estou criando várias Threads porém ao final ele não termina fica chamando sempre a mesma URL, mesmo eu passando urls diferentes.

Comment: @William editei a minha resposta, pois no final das contas ela sozinha não resolvia o seu problema. Por favor, me dê um feedback se entendi corretamente o seu fluxo e se consegui explicar a minha solução.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda estou estudando seu código para ver se vou conseguir fazer o que preciso. Só não entendi uma coisa, vou tentar te explicar melhor. Tenho várias paginas preciso simular uma ação de usuário que faz o seguinte: Acessa o site, escreve em um input e clica em um botão. Tudo isso já funciona porém o site após várias tentativas me bloqueia e só libera depois de 1 hora. Por isso precisa de Sleep. Ah  e grande jogada está no **webbrowser.DocumentCompleted += browser_coment_DocumentCompleted** Pois só depois de carregada a pagina consigo clicar no botão.

Comment: Se achar melhor posso te mandar a aplicação por email